# Django: How to call class-based generic views in views.py?

Tags: django-class-based-views, django-generic-views, django-1.4

I want to call class-based generic views in views.py

Please see my code...

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from crm.views import *

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^workDailyRecord/$', workDailyRecord),
)
```

and my views.py.... please watch...

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import TodayArchiveView
from crm.models import *

def workDailyRecord(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        tView.as_view() # I want call class-based generic views at this line.
    elif:
        """
        Probably this part will be code that save the data.
        """
        pass

class tView(TodayArchiveView):
    model = WorkDailyRecord
    context_object_name = 'workDailyRecord'
    date_field = 'date'
    template_name = "workDailyRecord.html"
```

What should I do?

Comment: `===` is not a thing in python.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Try this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view):

```
def workDailyRecord(request):
    if request.method === 'GET':
        return tView.as_view()(request)
```

Comment: url(r'^customer/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', customerDetailView.as_view())

Comment: def test(request):
　return customerDetailView.as_view(slug=slug)

Answer (score 1):

```
 def common_act(request, way, pk):
     types = {'grp':[10,'Group'],'std':[20,'Student']}
     events = {'crt':[1,'Create'], 'edt':[2,'Edit'], 'dlt':[3,'Delete']}
     ress = way.split('_')
     act_code = str(types[ress[1]][0] + events[ress[0]][0])

     action_way = {
            '11': CrtGroup,
           '12': EdtGroup,
           '13': DltGroup,
           '21': CrtStudent,
           '22': EdtStudent,
           '23': DltStudent
           }
return action_way[act_code].as_view()(request,pk=pk)
```

it`s work)))